# Build a chart using JS, AJAX, PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, morris.js

I have a problem and I can't resolve it, Please help me.
So I have my controller:

```
public function getJsonChart()
{
    $aNews = \News::select('title','created_at','views')->get();
    //echo json_encode($aNews);
    echo json_encode($aNews);
}
```

The json format is :

```
[
{
  "title": "First",
  "created_at": "2014-10-24 00:00:00",
  "views": 64
 },
{
  "title": "Second",
  "created_at": "2014-10-24 00:00:00",
  "views": 17
},
....................
]
```

My view:

```
<div id="graph"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/buildChart',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(outEvoVal) {
              console.log(outEvoVal);
              Morris.Line({
                element: 'graph',
                data: outEvoVal,
                xkey: 'd',
                ykeys: ['i','q'],
                labels: ['chaine','prea'],
                lineColors: ['#0000FF','#044c29'],
                lineWidth: 2
              });
            }
          });
    });
 </script>
```

I get an error and I don't understand where is this error:
       `TypeError: date is undefined` and this error points to line 616 of morris.js :
    `m = date.match(/^(\d+) Q(\d)$/);`

Please help me

Comment: What's hard to understand here? The date is undefined.

Comment: The error is exactly what it tells you. The variable `date` is not defined.

Comment: What date, what exacly I need to store in this variable?